# Python Pandas: Going through a list of cycles and making point of interest

Tags: python, pandas, max

To explain my problem easier I have created a dataset:

```
data = {'Cycle': ['Set1', 'Set1', 'Set1', 'Set2', 'Set2', 'Set2', 'Set2'],
        'Value': [1, 2.2, .5, .2,1,2.5,1]}
```

I want to create a loop that goes through the "Cycle" column and marks the max of each cycle with the letter A and the min with letter B, to output something like this:

```
POI = {'Cycle': ['Set1', 'Set1', 'Set1', 'Set2', 'Set2', 'Set2', 'Set2'],
        'Value': [1, 2.2, .5, .2,1,2.5,1],
         'POI': [0, 'A','B','B',0,'A',0]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(POI)
```

I am new to Python, so as much detail as possible would be very helpful, as well as I am not exactly sure how to go through each cycle on its own to get these values, so explaining that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `numpy.select` and `groupby.transform`:

```
g = df.groupby('Cycle')['Value']
df['POI'] = np.select([df['Value'].eq(g.transform('max')),
                       df['Value'].eq(g.transform('min'))],
                      ['A', 'B'])

# if you want 0 as default value (not '0')
df['POI'] = df['POI'].replace('0', 0)
```

output:

```
  Cycle  Value POI
0  Set1    1.0   0
1  Set1    2.2   A
2  Set1    0.5   B
3  Set2    0.2   B
4  Set2    1.0   0
5  Set2    2.5   A
6  Set2    1.0   0
```

Comment: @mozway can you please explain ('Cycle')['Value'], why you use ( for cycle ) and [ for value ] im trying to understand this better?

Comment: Please read the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) documentation. `('Cycle')` is a function call of `groupby`, while `['Value']` is slicing of the column.