# Python Pandas: Using groupby for to track POI's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

Im looking to mark key points in cycles based on certain conditions.

Here is the result I am looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data3 = {'Cycle': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2','2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
        'Value': [20, 24, 25, 18,15,12,1,2,19,18,12,1],
        'Diff2':[1,10,18,-12,-50,-14,14,150,130,-140,12,14],
        'POI':['-','-','A','-','B','-','-','-','A','B','-','-']} 
    
df = pd.DataFrame(Data3)
```

Based off another answer I understand I need to use groupby and have come up with something like this:

```
Data3['POI'] = np.select([Data3['Value'].eq(POI.transform('max')),
                          Data3['Diff2'].eq(POI.transform('min'))]
                         ['A','B'])
```

I need to mark A and B for each cycle, as shown in the Data frame above.

To get A: A is simply the max in the "Value" column

To get B: B is the minimum number in the Diff2 column

Im not sure how to use the groupby for multiple columns, so any help would be great.

```
Data3 = {'Cycle': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2','2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
        'Value': [20, 24, 25, 18,15,12,1,2,19,18,12,1],
        'Diff2':[1,10,18,-12,-50,-14,14,150,130,-140,12,14],
        } 

df = pd.DataFrame(Data3)


df['POI'] = Data3.groupby('Cycle').apply(
    lambda g: np.select([g['Value'] == g['Value'].max(),
                         g['Diff2'] == g['Diff2'].min()], ['A', 'B'], default='-')
).explode().set_axis(df.index, axis=0)
```

Comment: I just saw you already posted that question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547066/python-pandas-going-through-a-list-of-cycles-and-making-point-of-interest/73547158#73547158)? Why post it another time? The question got answered and accepted.... please delete this duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Going through a list of cycles and making point of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547066/python-pandas-going-through-a-list-of-cycles-and-making-point-of-interest)

Comment: This is different than that question

Comment: how exactly? find max of A and min of B in each group. Same to me

Comment: This takes into account values in multiple columns, where that only took into account values in a single column. I was not able to change that answer from yesterday to work, so i asked this question.

Comment: You have `Data3.groupby`. Replace `Data3` with `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it.
i created POI2, to have a comparison with the expected output

```
cond= [(df['Value'].eq(df.groupby('Cycle')['Value'].transform(max)) ),
       (df['Diff2'].eq(df.groupby('Cycle')['Diff2'].transform(min)) )]
choice=['A','B']
df['POI2'] = np.select(cond, choice, '-')
df
```

```
    Cycle    Value  Diff2   POI     POI2
0       1       20    1       -     -
1       1       24    10      -     -
2       1       25    18      A     A
3       1       18   -12      -     -
4       1       15   -50      B     B
5       1       12   -14      -     -
6       2       1     14      -     -
7       2       2    150      -     -
8       2       19   130      A     A
9       2       18  -140      B     B
10      2       12    12      -     -
11      2       1     14      -     -
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I am getting this error when trying: 'list' object has no attribute 'eq'

Comment: @SeanK22 maybe you forgot to convert a dictionary to a df?

Comment: @SeanK22, i used the data you provided in the question

Comment: @SeanK22 I added notebook screenshot

Answer (score 2):

```py
df['POI'] = df.groupby('Cycle').apply(
    lambda g: np.select([g['Value'] == g['Value'].max(),
                         g['Diff2'] == g['Diff2'].min()], ['A', 'B'], default='-')
    ).explode().set_axis(df.index, axis=0)
```

Comment: sure that works like that on your side? I couldn't assign it as a new column till I added `reset_index(drop=True)` .. because after the groupby it has several one's and two's as index

Comment: @Rabinzel, yes, thank you - I rushed a bit

Comment: I am getting this error when trying this? AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: is your `df` a dict? I tried it with your data from question, and it worked

Comment: @SeanK22, this solution also works. seems DF is not defined when you're validating these solutions

Comment: Hmm okay, I updated the question with what exactly I am running.